# root cron job doesn't work (18.04 LTS SERVER)

Tags: cron, dd

As a root I run three **dd** processes in the background

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null &
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null &
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null &
```

As a root I edit a crontab and put a job to kill all dd processes that were run by root every minute

```
crontab -e 

* * * * * pkill -u root dd
```

But when I use **top**  to monitor processes the dd processes don't get killed. Why ?

Messages from /var/log/syslog :

```
Dec  9 12:33:01 champion CRON[3395]: Authentication failure
Dec  9 12:33:29 champion crontab[3383]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Dec  9 12:34:01 champion cron[1432]: Authentication failure
Dec  9 12:34:01 champion CRON[3398]: Authentication failure
```

Tried these suggestions but it didn't help :

1. Invoke the crontab with :

   crontab -e -u root
2. Make sure that you have an empty line at the end of the cronjob file, meaning that every line ends with a newline.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the `/etc/pam.d/cron` file?

Comment: No I haven't. Do I need to ?

Comment: No you don't (and you shouldn't unless you really know what you're doing). Does `sudo pwck -qr /etc/passwd /etc/shadow` produce any output?

Comment: It does : 

sudo: unable to resolve host champion
no matching password file entry in /etc/shadow
add user 'root' in /etc/shadow? No
pwck: no changes

Comment: OK so it sounds like the issue is the same as described here [root cron jobs don't run and give "authentication error"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1054283&p=6641878#post6641878). It *should* be possible to fix by running `pwck` in read-write mode i.e. plain `sudo pwck` without the `-r` or other arguments - please try it and report back. You also appear to have an problem with your hostname but that is separate issue I think.

Comment: The output of plain `sudo pwck` : 
no matching password file entry in /etc/shadow
add user 'root' in /etc/shadow?

Comment: Yes you should accept the suggested action to add the user `root` to your shadow file

Comment: I accepted to add the user root to **/etc/shadow** and now everything works ! Thank you steeldriver

Comment: Great - I have added an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the following diagnostic output from `pwck -r`:

```
no matching password file entry in /etc/shadow add user 'root' in /etc/shadow?
```

you can see that the problem is the same as described here:

- [root cron jobs don't run and give "authentication error"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1054283&p=6641878#post6641878)

You can fix it by running `pwck` again, this time in read-write mode

```
sudo pwck
```

and accepting the suggested action to add the appropriate shadow file entry for user root.

Comment: Thank you steeldriver !

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you're writing the crontab with root?

```
sudo crontab -e
```

A non-root account would not be able to kill processes owned by root.

Comment: did everything while being a root (sudo -i)

Comment: I've tested this on my system (Ubuntu 20.10) and it works. Rather than using `pkill`, though, I used: `* * * * * killall -u root dd`. This should not matter, though, as `pkill` and `killall` will do essentially the same thing for this situation. 

Comment: It doesn't work on mine. 
I keep getting  "Authentication Failure" when I check /var/log/syslog.

Comment: I've tried it on my Desktop 18.04 and it worked. 
However on 18.04 SERVER it didn't work.